# Nested JSON into flutter

Tags: android, json, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to deal with nested JSON file that is taken from Firebase (realtime) This is the JSON file. The first child (12341) is an ID, and then year, month, day and just then details about a student.

```
{
  "12341" : {
    "2014" : {
      "11" : {
        "21" : {
          "class" : "taichi",
          "name" : "mukuro"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I've done before is simply mapped those value into a list, however it will result all those from year until its final child

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    print(data.keys.elementAt(i));
    studMap = {
        data.keys.elementAt(i): data.values.elementAt(i),
    };
    stud.add(studMap);
}
```

I'm not sure what to do since id,year,month,and day is a Key.
I want to be able to display list of students(using listview) that will show the id, date, name and class

Comment: This is definitely due to the way you declared/initialized the variable `databaseReference`. Could you also include it in the question?

Answer (score 2):

First create the map

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
```

Then you can iterate through the keys to get the values of the children

```
map.forEach((key, value) {
final class = value["class"]
final id = value["id"]
final name = value["name"]
}
```